# Multiple states load to separate ui-view in ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-route

I am facing a problem that how I can create the separate window for every state.

Suppose I have three states like `state1`, `state2` and `state3`, normally when I call `state1` then the template of `state1` is placed into `<div ui-view></div>` and when I call `state2` then the template of `state2` is also placed into `<div ui-view></div>`.

But I want to create ui-view=’view1’ and ui-view=’view2’ dynamically. After that I will place the whole HTML into my custom window, the custom window looks like desktop window.

Do you have any idea to fix this my problem?

Comment: this is not possible. angular is single page application. you should not do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "create ui-view='view` and... 'view2' dynamically" ? Which part is dynamic? Also what is a "custom window"? Can you be more precise with you question?

Comment: yes i want to use custom window with ui-router